# IIS Windows Authentication IIS APPOOL

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis

I have a intranet website that I have developed that I want to use windows Authentication.

In my code I use the following to get the username from the logged on user to display at the top of the page.

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        ThisLoginName.Text = userName.ToString();
```

However what does display at the top of the username **"IIS APPPOOL\WebsiteName"** I have changed the IIS 7.0 Authentication to Windows Auth only.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: are you impersonating?

Comment: <identity impersonate ="false"/> if i set that to true it gives me an error

Comment: go check out [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1507047.aspx?WindowsIdentity%20GetCurrent%20Name%20vs%20User%20Identity%20Name) link which will give you an overview of authentication at IIS level.

Answer (score 2):

You should use: `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` to get the name of the authenticated user. Your code returns the user name for the user that runs your web process on the server.

Comment: um, Still the same issue.